# REGEXP in MYSQL Join works improperly

Tags: mysql, regex, join

I have a next mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    shop_sections.title, 
    shop_sections.id, 
    shop_sections.parent_id, 
    count(shop_items.id) AS items
FROM 
    shop_sections 
LEFT JOIN 
    shop_items 
ON 
    shop_items.section_id 
        REGEXP "^" + shop_sections.parent_id + "([[.full-stop.]].*|$)" 
GROUP BY 
    shop_sections.id
```

REGEXP perform not properly. For row `shop_items.section_id` = 1 it gets all rows with field `shop_items.section_id` that are started with '1' (i.e. 13.14 or 13.15, but it must get whether 1 or 1.* (1.1, 1.2, 1.2.3 and the like)).

I've noticed that if change

`REGEXP "^" + shop_sections.parent_id + "([[.full-stop.]].*|$)"`

to

`REGEXP "^1([[.full-stop.]].*|$)"`

than it works properly for 1 (and also for any value if insert it to the query manually). But I want to fetch all items using one query.

What may be the problem?

**UPD.**

`shop_items.section_id` contains values in the next form: parent_section.child_section_1.child_section_2.child_section_3 etc. I need this for pagination on item's pages.

Values in `shop_sections.parent_id` have the same form.

All I want to do is to show a tree of sections and a number of items for every section.

Comment: Why do you use it in `ON` section? Where is your join condition? How `shop_sections` is related to `shop_items`

Comment: Join condition is `REGEXP`. Earlier for this query I was using `LIKE`, but I needed `REGEXP`.

Comment: Oh god, it's really a terrible schema then

Comment: Then how it can be done without `REGEXP` in `ON` condition?

Comment: I'm sure relation between tables (entities) should be organized as a straight equality.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something or my question isn't clear but I think it can't be done with one to one relationship (did you mean that?) because one item can belong to few sections (i.e. item "Book Different Seasons" belongs to section "Horror books" and also to "Books", "Books" is a parent section and "Horror books" is a child section).

Comment: that's where one-to-many or many-to-many comes to help you.

Comment: But I've already have many-to-many relationship. The problem is that MYSQL REGEXP works improperly (or more likely I do something wrong).

Comment: nope. The problem is that you've implemented many-to-many following terribly wrong way. With real N:M you have another relations table and use `=` in join condition, without any REGEXes or LIKEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` can't be used for concatenation in MySQL. Your test should be :

```
ON 
  shop_items.section_id 
    REGEXP CONCAT('^', shop_sections.parent_id, '([[.full-stop.]].*|$)')
```

The strange results you get are due to the broken concatenation performing an addition instead. Suppose `shop_sections.parent_id` is 1, then :

```
'^' + shop_sections.parent_id + '([[.full-stop.]].*|$)'
```

... is really evaluated `0 + 1 + 0` (strings cast as integers are evaluated as 0 unless they begin with a sequence of numbers), which used as a regular expression is equivalent to a useless `'1'`.